# Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed in \tableofcontents and bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, soul, scrreprt

I'm writing a book in a scrreprt format. And, for the spacing and underlining the sections, I'm using the soul package. However, it throws an error in tableofcontents and bibliography. I'm clueless how to rectify this problem.

Here is the sample code:

...

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, twoside, openright, parskip,fleqn]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{xyz.bib}
    @article{two,
        title={Die neuen Vierventil-Ottomotoren fur die mittlere Braureihe von Mercedes-Benz (Germany)},
        author={Abthoff, Von J and Huttebraucker, D and Zahn, W and Bockel, H},
        journal={Mtz},
        volume={53},
        pages={496--508},
        year={1992}
    }
    @inproceedings{three,
        title={Strategies for NOx reduction in heavy duty engines},
        author={Al-Sened, A and Karimi, E},
        booktitle={Proceedings of the 23rd CIMAC Congress},
        year={2001}
    }
    
    @misc{four,
        title={Deutsche Stiftung Weltbevölkerung},
        author={Bundesministerium für Wirtschaft und Arbeit},
        year={2003/04},
        publisher={NOAA}
    }
    
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\fontsize{14}{16.8}\bfseries}
{\ul{\thechapter\enspace}}
{0em}
{\ul}
\setul{0.3pt}{1.5pt}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}
{\ul{\thesection\enspace}}
{0em}
{\ul}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}
{\ul{\thesubsection\enspace}}
{0em}
{\ul}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}
{\ul{\thesubsubsection\enspace}}
{0em}
{\ul}


\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\setmathfont{GFSNeohellenicMath.otf}%equation font in arial font
\setmathfont[range=up]{Arial}
\setmathfont[range=it]{Arial Italic}
\setmathfont[range=bfup]{Arial Bold}
\setmathfont[range=bfit]{Arial Bold Italic}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN} 
\bibpunct{/}{/}{;}{n}{}{,}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{/#1/}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Thermodynamics}
\section{Heat}
Propagation of turbulent flames \cite{two} in spark-ignition engines is considered from the viewpoint of the different possible regimes \cite{three} of premixed turbulent combustion.\cite{four} Nondimensional parameters defining known combustion regimes are reviewed, 

    \medskip
    
    \bibliography{xyz}

\end{document}
```

...

Comment: are you using lualatex?

Comment: Yes. Should I use something else? This is because there are some packages and function that works only on lualatex.

Comment: with lualatex you could use the lua-ul package instead of soul (this needs a current tex system).

Comment: Why would you underline section titles to begin with?

Comment: This is the format that I want to produce. That's why.

Comment: You should be aware of the fact that KoMaScript classes don't like `titlesec`.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that. But, some features that I want is satisfied with titlesec and some from KoMaScript. Can we produce the same effect by using single one? Do you think that the problem lies here with the incompatibility of titlesec with KoMaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `soul` doesn't like `\@mkboth` at all.

If you don't need headers, the solution is to locally neutralize the command.

Beware that `scrreprt` doesn't really like `titlesec`. And also that underlining (especially so tight) is not typographycally very sound.

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{two,
        title={Die neuen Vierventil-Ottomotoren fur die mittlere Braureihe von Mercedes-Benz (Germany)},
        author={Abthoff, Von J and Huttebraucker, D and Zahn, W and Bockel, H},
        journal={Mtz},
        volume={53},
        pages={496--508},
        year={1992}
    }
    @inproceedings{three,
        title={Strategies for NOx reduction in heavy duty engines},
        author={Al-Sened, A and Karimi, E},
        booktitle={Proceedings of the 23rd CIMAC Congress},
        year={2001}
    }
    
    @misc{four,
        title={Deutsche Stiftung Weltbevölkerung},
        author={Bundesministerium für Wirtschaft und Arbeit},
        year={2003/04},
        publisher={NOAA}
    }
    
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, twoside, openright, parskip,fleqn]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\setul{0.3pt}{1.5pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ulex}[1]{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo % neutralize \@mkboth in unnumbered chapters
  \expanded{\noexpand\ul{#1}}}
\makeatother

\titleformat{name=\chapter}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{16.8}\bfseries}
  {\ul{\thechapter\enspace}}
  {0em}
  {\ul}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{16.8}\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\ulex}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}
  {\ul{\thesection\enspace}}
  {0em}
  {\ul}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}
  {\ul{\thesubsection\enspace}}
  {0em}
  {\ul}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}
  {\ul{\thesubsubsection\enspace}}
  {0em}
  {\ul}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\setmathfont{GFSNeohellenicMath.otf}%equation font in arial font
\setmathfont[range=up]{Arial}
\setmathfont[range=it]{Arial Italic}
\setmathfont[range=bfup]{Arial Bold}
\setmathfont[range=bfit]{Arial Bold Italic}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN} 
\bibpunct{/}{/}{;}{n}{}{,}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{/#1/}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Thermodynamics}
\section{Heat}
Propagation of turbulent flames \cite{two} in spark-ignition engines is considered from the viewpoint of the different possible regimes \cite{three} of premixed turbulent combustion.\cite{four} Nondimensional parameters defining known combustion regimes are reviewed, 

    \medskip
    
    \bibliography{xyz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works.